# Finding the order of $\langle a,b | a^{8}=b^{2}=1, ab=ba^{3}\rangle.$

Tags: abstract-algebra, finite-groups, group-presentation, combinatorial-group-theory

Im new at abstract algebra stuff and im wondering whats the technique to prove this kind of stuff.

Question:

Let $G=\langle a,b | a^{8}=b^{2}=1, ab=ba^{3}\rangle$, prove that $|G|=16 $ and find all subgroups or order $8$.

I can calculate all the elements of $G$, then I showed by brute force that $G$ has only $16$ elements but I cant give a real proof of that.

Any help will be really appreciated, thanks for the help. :D

Comment: These problems will usually have two steps: First find a way to represent the elements that clearly give the desired order (i.e. something like being of them form $a^nb^m$ with suitable bounds on $n$ and $m$). This shows that the order is at most the given number. To show that it has that order, you need to find an example of a group with that order and generators satisfying the relations.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is easy to see that $G$ can have at most $16$ elements, because we can 
list all elements in the form $b^sa^r$ with $0\le r\le 7$ and $0\le s\le 1$ by using $ab=ba^3$. On the other hand, such a group is given by $SD_2$, the *semidihedral group of degree $2$*. For further details see the classifcation of all groups of order $16$ [here](https://www.google.at/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=2ahUKEwjJ3fPRyMfhAhVH_qQKHRvtBToQFjAAegQIARAC&url=http%3A%2F%2Fbuzzard.ups.edu%2Fcourses%2F2012spring%2Fprojects%2Fclausen-groups-16-ups-434-2012.pdf&usg=AOvVaw2L4wLgmlEPSP2nvHON6iIE).

Comment: Thanks so much for the reference and for your answer. Now, whats the theorem you used to say that since $0\leq r \leq 7$ and $0\leq s \leq 1$? or is it because we only have 2 options for s and 8 options for r? Sorry for the basic questions :x

Comment: I used that you can convert any word starting with $ab$ into a word starting with $ba^3$ by using the given relations, and any power of $a$ to $a^r$ with $0\le r\le 7$ because of $a^8=e$. So $a^8=a^0$, $a^9=a^1$ etc.

Comment: All clear now, thanks mister!